# WebView com alguns problemas em swift

Tags: ios, swift

Tenho 1 problema

Código simples:

```
let url = "http://apple.com"


override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

let requestURL = NSURL(string:url)
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
webView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

essa webview não esta carregando o site responsivo, carrega normal com um zoom horrivel,  alguem sabe o porque?

Comment: Testei esse mesmo código e funcionou em todas as versões no simulador. Ficou responsivo e não ficou preto. Talvez o problema esteja na interface (usei **storyboard**) ou qualquer outra configuração de ambiente. É possível informar mais detalhes?

Comment: agora rodou em todos emuladores, mas o problema do responsivo continua, ele carrega com o zooom horrivel, e nao aparece o menu de opções (q sites responsivo deve aparecer), quando adiciona os botoes, de atualizar, anterior e próximo na webview, funciona normalmente. se eu remover eles, nao fica responsivo.

Comment: se puder me ajudar

Comment: Pois então, nunca me deparei com isso, por isso perguntei sobre mais detalhes além deste código apenas. Se quiser, [baixe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1o0NIBAU7UjVWVZSXFyYVc5UU0/view?usp=sharing) o exemplo que fiz simplesmente com um *web view*, abrindo o site responsivo de qualquer forma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Garanta que a sua `UIWebView` tem o tamanho necessário para mostrar o conteúdo.
Uma sugestão é criar `NSLayoutConstraints` para que funcione em todos os dispositivos.

Comment: era isso nao tava mostrando tudo valeu